# What is the difference between "-r profile" and "require 'profile'"?

Tags: ruby, profiler

My Ruby version is 1.9.3p448.

I have a simple program:

```
count = 0
words = File.open('/usr/share/dict/words')

while word = words.gets
  word.chomp!
  count += 1 if word.length == 12
end

puts "#{count} twelve-character words"
```

When I evaluate it with `ruby -r profile test.rb`, the output is:

```
7226 twelve-character words
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
  9.63     0.44      0.44   119095     0.00     0.00  String#chomp!
  9.19     0.86      0.42   119095     0.00     0.00  Fixnum#==
  6.35     1.15      0.29   119095     0.00     0.00  String#length
  5.91     1.42      0.27   119096     0.00     0.00  IO#gets
  0.66     1.45      0.03     7226     0.00     0.00  Fixnum#+
  0.00     1.45      0.00        2     0.00     0.00  IO#set_encoding
  0.00     1.45      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  IO#open
  0.00     1.45      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  File#initialize
  0.00     1.45      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Fixnum#to_s
  0.00     1.45      0.00        2     0.00     0.00  IO#write
  0.00     1.45      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  IO#puts
  0.00     1.45      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Kernel.puts
  0.00     4.57      0.00        1     0.00  4570.00  #toplevel
```

But, when I add `require 'profile'` at the beginning of the program, and then evaluate it with `ruby test.rb`, the output is:

```
7226 twelve-character words
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
 25.61     0.63      0.63   119095     0.01     0.01  String#chomp!
 16.67     1.04      0.41   119096     0.00     0.00  IO#gets
  0.00     1.04      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Fixnum#to_s
  0.00     1.04      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  IO#open
  0.00     1.04      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  File#initialize
  0.00     1.04      0.00        2     0.00     0.00  IO#write
  0.00     1.04      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  IO#puts
  0.00     1.04      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Kernel.puts
  0.00     2.46      0.00        1     0.00  2460.00  #toplevel
```

It seems that the second way lost some methods, like `Fixnum#==`, `Fixnum#+`, `String#length` and `IO#set_encoding`.

Why doesn't it have the same result as the first one?

Comment: I get this behavior with 2.1.1p76 as well.

Comment: I also get the full output if I do `require 'profile'; load 'test.rb'` in irb. So this doesn't appear to be some quirk in the `-r` option.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [profile documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/profiler/rdoc/Profiler__.html) there should be no difference. I have created a [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9703) for this.